# iOS Beginner: String concatenation

Tags: iphone, ios

I've concatenated string using the following code:

```
NSString *add = @"a ";
lbl.text = [add stringByAppendingString:lbl.text];
```

*Which adds 'a ' to lbl variable every time I call the function.*

But for some reason this method concatenates in a way that the new string adds in the beginning of what's already there, and not to the end.

Instead of getting AAABBB, I get BBBAAA. How do I fix this?

Comment: do you want to append lbl.text before add, or vice versa. What are references for AAA and BBB. is it lbl.text= AAA and add= BBB?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I mean. Say a = "AAA", b = "BBB", how do I a+b that gives "AAABBB", not "BBBAAA"? Because this is what I get using the method above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `a = AAA` and `b = BBB` then you will need to write

```
[a stringByAppendingString:b];
```

So in your case it will be
`[lbl.text stringByAppendingString:add];` as `lbl.text = AAA` and `add = BBB`.

For more information about this method please see [NSString documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
  NSMutableString *aString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"AAA"];
  NSMutableString *bString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"BBB"];

  [aString appendString:bString];   
  NSLog(@"Astring:%@",aString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use NSMutableString. Declare an `NSMutableString *s`, and then call `[s appendString:..]`, or you can also call `[s appendFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"",];`